# Covert long type to date format in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

How to convert Long "1206946690" to date format "yyyy-mm-dd" using Pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need to use `pyspark` for this thing whatsoever.

Converting from UNIX timestamp to date is covered in Python's standard library's `datetime` module, just use it.

Example:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def to_date(n):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(n).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
>>> to_date(1206946690)
'2008-03-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

see documentation ; extra thing is cast to date as below example.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime.html

pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime(timestamp: ColumnOrName, format: str = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') → pyspark.sql.column.Column[source]
Converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a string representing the timestamp of that moment in the current system time zone in the given format.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/Los_Angeles")
time_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1428476400,)], ['unix_time'])
time_df.select(from_unixtime('unix_time').cast("date"))
```

you need to cast as date to return required `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1206946690,)], ["timestamp"])
df = df.withColumn("date", F.from_unix_time(df["timestamp"], "yyyy-MM-dd").cast(TimestampType()))
df.show()
```